# Trying to display a message on UITableView if data cannot be retrieved from Firebase Real Time Database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**Background**

I am currently building a task manager feature in my iOS app. Users can add/complete tasks for each day of the week.

When a user goes to add a task under a certain day, a reference is made to that specific day, and the task is listed under that day in Firebase RTD.

`let ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "users").child("profile").child(uid).child("todos").child(String(self.getDate(self.dayNum)))`

(The getDate function is what I use to get the current day in terms of numbers. Ex Feb 18 would be "18")

Adding and storing the tasks works completely fine. The tasks are always stored under the correct users profile, todo list path, and day.

**Problem**

The issue comes when a user goes to add a task to a day with no previous tasks stored in the database.

When you toggle between different days, such as going from the "26" to the "27", if there are previous tasks stored in the database then it will load each days tasks fine and update the table accordingly.

But this is only the case if the days have previous tasks that are already stored in Firebase RTD.

If you have no tasks for a certain day stored in Firebase, the UiTableView simply presents the tasks stored for the previous day you had selected because it cannot find the path in RTD.

For example, if you had clicked on "27", and it had two tasks stored for that day, then moved to day "28", which had no tasks stored for that day, it would present the tasks from day 27 on day 28.

I understand the reason for this is that the reference cannot find the path in Firebase RTD when going to load the tasks, since there are no tasks to load and thus the path does not exist.

I attempted to comment next to my code to explain everything that is happening

```
func loadTodos(n: Int){
        self.todos.removeAll() //removes all tasks from the array "todos"
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }  //gets current user uid
         let ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "users").child("profile").child(uid).child("todos").child(String(getDate(n)) //creates path to Firebase for specific day

 ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
            for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]{
                let todoName = child.key
                let todoRef = ref.child(todoName)
                
                todoRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (todoSnapshot) in
                    let value = todoSnapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                    let isChecked = value!["isChecked"] as? Bool
                    
                    self.todos.append(Todo(isChecked: isChecked!, todoName: todoName)) //adds new todo to array "todos"
                    self.todoTV.reloadData() //reloads UITableView "todoTV"
                }
            }//end of for
        }//end of .observeSingleEvent
    }//end of func
```

**Question**

I am looking to see if there is a way you can detect that the path does not exist, and present some type of message instead of the wrong days tasks.

I think it could be something as easy as an if/else statement to detect if the path exists, and if not present a message. I am just not sure how to do it.

I am open to any other solution really.

My goal is that I would ideally like to place a message under the days with no tasks, such as "Add a task", that would disappear once a task is added.

Comment: I believe firebase has a .exists() function. I think you can call something like "Database.database().....child("todos").exists()" and it will return true or false.. and then handle the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Whats Happening

You're only reloading your tableView in the `for` loop.

That means if the for loop has zero items, your table never gets reloaded.

## How to Fix It

Here's where you're currently reloading your `tableView`.

```
todoRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (todoSnapshot) in
                    let value = todoSnapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                    let isChecked = value!["isChecked"] as? Bool
                    
                    self.todos.append(Todo(isChecked: isChecked!, todoName: todoName)) //adds new todo to array "todos"
                    self.todoTV.reloadData() //reloads UITableView "todoTV"
                }
```

Instead of having it only in the second callback. Add it to the first one too. Like this:

```swift
func loadTodos(n: Int){
        self.todos.removeAll() //removes all tasks from the array "todos"
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }  //gets current user uid
         let ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "users").child("profile").child(uid).child("todos").child(String(getDate(n)) //creates path to Firebase for specific day

 ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
            for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]{
                let todoName = child.key
                let todoRef = ref.child(todoName)
                
                todoRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (todoSnapshot) in
                    let value = todoSnapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                    let isChecked = value!["isChecked"] as? Bool
                    
                    self.todos.append(Todo(isChecked: isChecked!, todoName: todoName)) //adds new todo to array "todos"
                    self.todoTV.reloadData() //reloads UITableView "todoTV"
                }
            }//end of for
// ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- -----
            self.todoTV.reloadData() // ---- Reload Data Here Too ----
// ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- -----
        }//end of .observeSingleEvent
    }//end of func
```

This way if the loop has no items, the table will still reload with the empty data.